# Kryonet not receiving custom classes

Tags: java, kryonet

I'm trying to set up a basic client and server to get the hang of networking, but I'm running into a problem.

Whenever I send a class with one of my own classes as a variable, the server does not receive it. I can use a string/int/etc for the variable perfectly fine but whenever a variable of my own type is included it is not received, along with all objects I try to send after it.

Everything is registered with Kryo. Am I just missing something? Any help is appreciated!

From GameClient:

```
public GameClient(String name) {
    client = new Client();
    client.start();

    NetworkManager.register(client);

    listener = new ClientListener();
    client.addListener(listener);

    try {
        client.connect(5000, "24.207.67.56", NetworkManager.port);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Login login2 = new Login();
    User user2 = new User(name);
    login2.user = user2;
    login2.name = user2.name;
    client.sendTCP(login2); // server does not recieve this

    Login login = new Login();
    login.name = user.name;
    client.sendTCP(login); // server receives this only when it is sent before the Login containing the User

}
```

From GameServer :

```
public GameServer() {
    server = new Server();

    NetworkManager.register(server);

    listener = new ServerListener(server);
    server.addListener(listener);

    try {
        server.bind(NetworkManager.port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    server.start();
}
```

In ServerListener:

```
@Override
public void received(Connection c, Object o) {
    System.out.println("recieved");
    if (o instanceof Login) {
        System.out.println("[SERVER] " + ((Login) o).name + " logged in.");
        LoginResult lr = new LoginResult();
        lr.result = true;
        c.sendTCP(lr);
    }
}
```

From NetworkManager:

```
public static void register(EndPoint endPoint) {
    Kryo kryo = endPoint.getKryo();
    kryo.register(Login.class);
    kryo.register(User.class);
}

public static class Login {
    public User user;
    public String name;
}
```

User:

```
public class User {
    public String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the [relevant parts of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than just describing it in general terms. Explain *specifically* what you're trying to accomplish and how your results differ from the desired results. Please read this [advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem was caused by the lack of default constructor in the User class. Removing the `User(String name)` constructor or adding a plain `User()` constructor fixes the issue.

It would be useful if it threw an error when you tried to do it incorrectly, but oh well.